# Return Objects Based on Filter Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, filter

I have a state in the JSON format below, and I also have a checkbox state for when categories gets selected.

```
initialData = [
  { store_name: 'Shop 1',
    women: false,
    men: false,
    kids: true},
  { store_name: 'Shop 2',
    women: true,
    men: false,
    kids: false},
  { store_name: 'Shop 3',
    women: false,
    men: true,
    kids: true}
]
```

How do I write update the showFilteredResults function that filters initialData based on the filteredArray?

i.e. if filteredArray = ['kids', 'men'], output should return data for key 0 (shop 1) and key 2 (shop 2) where kids = true OR men = true. The current function I have shows all results.

```
const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}])
    
const [Filters, setFilters] = useState({
        categories: []
    })

//tried the function below, which does not work
const showFilteredResults = (filteredArray) => {
   let filteredResults = initialData.filter( function(main_el) {
       return filteredArray.filter(function(e){
           return main_el.e ===true;})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by looking for one of the filter keys.

```js
const 
    initialData = [{ store_name: 'Shop 1', women: false, men: false, kids: true }, { store_name: 'Shop 2', women: true, men: false, kids: false }, { store_name: 'Shop 3', women: false, men: true, kids: true }],
    filteredArray = ['kids', 'men'], 
    result = initialData.filter(object => filteredArray.some(key => object[key]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const initialData = [
  { store_name: 'Shop 1',
    women: false,
    men: false,
    kids: true},
  { store_name: 'Shop 2',
    women: true,
    men: false,
    kids: false},
  { store_name: 'Shop 3',
    women: false,
    men: true,
    kids: true}
]
const filter = ['kids', 'mens'];
const showFilteredResults = (filteredArray) => initialData.filter(data => filter.some(a => data[a]));

console.log(showFilteredResults(filter))
```